# How do I set up a Game Center leaderboard?

Tags: xcode, game-center

I am using regular Objective-C in Xcode.

I created a Game Center leaderboard on iTunes Connect. When my app is opened, it asks for a login the first time, then checks to see if you're already signed in or not every other time after that.

I also have a high score saved as a userDefault integer. I just don't know how to take my int "HighScore", create a public leader board, and then put everyone's HighScore on to the leaderboard. How can I accomplish this?

I cannot find any tutorials on making leaderboards and Apple's developer website just doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
//Define UserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//Create Score with leaderboardIdentifier
GKScore *newScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"leaderboardIdentifier"];
newScore.value = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"highScore"];

//Submit Score
[GKScore reportScores:@[newScore] withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much! I have literally spent a weeks time trying to figure this out and everything has been so complex and confusing but this is so simple and easy